# Can I make it so that the topbar only appears on mouseover in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I'd like for the topbar to disappear and only appear on mouseover. I went into the profiles tab and then I tried to do some code. I tried this code.

```
#tabbrowser-tabs
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

It makes the tabs disappear but the URL bar still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, `#nav-bar` which contains URL bar and `#TabsToolbar` which contains nav bar are two different things. I have implemented a related one on `#nav-bar` before:

```css
#TabsToolbar { /* tab bar */
  /* 1 should be at top */
-moz-box-ordinal-group: 1 !important;
}
#PersonalToolbar { /* bookmarks toolbar */
-moz-box-ordinal-group: 2 !important;
}
#nav-bar { /* main toolbar containing address bar, search bar, add-on icons */
-moz-box-ordinal-group: 3 !important;
}

#nav-bar { /* main toolbar containing address bar, search bar, add-on icons */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav-bar:hover {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: show;
}
#nav-bar:focus-within {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: show;
}
#content-deck{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

It has the behavior as follows:

- The url bar is hidden by default
- The url bar will appear when it is focused or hovered. You can use <kbd>F6</kbd> to focus it.